# Differential Calculus in non-metric spaces

Tags: derivatives

Is it possible to develop Differential Calculus in non-metric spaces? In other words, is it possible to apply the concept of derivative to non-metric sets?

Comment: it depends about what you think is a derivative or how you want to generalize the concept of derivative to arbitrary topological spaces. But I think that the answer is no because basically the derivatives are built under the concept of distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to develop some amount of differential calculus even without the notion of a *space*! E.g. see [derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra)) and [Kähler differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_differential) only needs the notion of a ring.

The Leibniz rule seems to be the most important feature of the concept of differentials.